# How does PHP set the PHPSESSID into $_COOKIE superglobal variable without using the function setcookie() or setrawcookie()?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm learning PHP's most important and difficult to understand concepts viz. **"Session and Cookies"**

As per my understanding cookies can only be set into the browser by using either of `setcookie()` or `setrawcookie()` functions.

As per my understanding of session process, it works in following way.

- Every session is started by using the session_start( ) function.
- The session_start( ) function must come before any HTML, including blank lines, on the page.
- The session_start( ) function generates a random Session Id and stores it in a cookie on the user's computer (this is the only session information that is actually stored on the client side.)
- The default name for the cookie is `PHPSESSID`. To reference the session Id in my PHP code, I would therefore reference the variable $PHPSESSID (it's a cookie name)

**Please correct me if my understanding is wrong anywhere in above explanation.**

My doubt is as session is setting some value in `$_COOKIE` superglobal it's nowhere using any of the functions `setcookie() or setrawcookie()` then still how could session id gets stored as a cookie variable?

If I assume that the session id is set as a cookie variable and `setccookie() or setrawcookie()` might have been called internally then what are the parameter values set while calling either of the functions  `setccookie() or setrawcookie()` to set the cookie value?

Thank You.

Comment: No, you don't want to reference `$PHPSESSID`. To get the session ID, call `session_id()` with no arguments. It will return the current session.

Comment: Yes, `session_start` will create a `$_COOKIE` value. No, you shouldn't directly interact with this value via the various cookie functions - let PHP handle it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Nitpick: `session_start` won't create anything in `$_COOKIE`; it requires another roundtrip for the cookie to appear there… :-P

Comment: Technically speaking `setcookie` does not set anything on the browser. It modifies an internal cookies array which it then uses to tell the browser that the server would like it to remember some cookies. The browser can choose to completely ignore this.

Comment: It's all somewhat academic anyway, since the session id might not even be persisted by a cookie. The long and short of it is that when dealing with the session, deal with the session - the cookie is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The default name for the cookie is `PHPSESSID`. To reference the session Id in my PHP code, I would therefore reference the variable `$PHPSESSID`

No, it is just the name of the cookie, it will not be set as a global variable. You can access the value in `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']`. But really, this should not concern you at all, you should only use the [`session_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) and the `$_SESSION` superglobal to interact with PHP's session API, the underlying cookie being used is none of your concern for most intents and purposes.

> … it's nowhere using any of the functions `setcookie()` or `setrawcookie()` …
>
> If I assume that the session id is set as a cookie variable and `setccookie()` or `setrawcookie()` might have been called internally …

Yes, PHP is calling *some* functions internally that will set the cookies. It's probably neither `setcookie` nor `setrawcookie` but some internal C function that sets the cookie. Again, it's none of your concern really. You just need to understand that calling `session_start` will somehow internally cause a cookie to be set.

> … then what are the parameter values set while calling either of the functions `setccookie()` or `setrawcookie()` to set the cookie value?

Those are determined by [the various `session.cookie_*` parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) you can set via [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) or [`ini_set`](http://php.net/ini_set).

Comment: "You can access the value in $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']." Maybe! But don't depend on doing so, as the name of the cookie is configurable.

Comment: Sure, `$_COOKIE[session_name()]` would be more correct; but again, you should hardly ever need to poke around there at all.

Comment: Agreed entirely on that.